# What to do after Rails deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I am am a newbie in Ruby on Rails development and I am learning this fantastic framework fast and easy. The only problem (which is a big one) is how to deploy.

I have tried a Linode StackScript which installs Ruby, Rails, Passenger and Nginx and I have made a "cap deploy" and all files was sent to the server but how on earth do I get this public. When I visit my website (IP) it seems to be down or not responding. Is there anything I need to do after deployment to make my app available to the web?

Thankful for all help, I really want to slay the deployment beast!

Comment: Without any more input we probably can't proceed. What exactly does the server respond and do you have the chance to have look at the server logs?

Comment: When I visit the IP address in the browser my app is not shown. Nothing is shown. The server does not seem to be running, but I belive it is. Should I not be able to visit the IP and see my app after deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ease of deployment, and scalability, have you looked at [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) instead of hosting your own server?

That would make the process of deploying as simple as `git push heroku`

Comment: Yes, but they are so expensive and I cannot use for example jRuby or graph databases like Neo4j. And Rails 3 does not seem to be supported.

Comment: I don't know about your other points, but I do know for a fact that Rails 3 is supported. I am currently developing a Rails 3 app and deploy to Heroku frequently for integration testing.

Comment: I find it hard to understand the dyno concept. If I for example got 100 visitors at the same time, how many dynos should I use?